# Changing css of single li element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change edit the css of only 4th tab of this li menu. If so, how?

All help appreciated. Thank you!

```html
<div class="rt_tabs clearfix  left tab-style-2" id="single-product-details" data-tab-style="tab-style-2">
  <ul class="tab_nav hidden-xs">
    <li class="tab_title  active" id="tab-1-title" data-tab-number="1"><span class="icon-lightbulb"></span>TAB 1</li>
    <li class="tab_title " id="tab-2-title" data-tab-number="2"><span class="icon-home"></span>TAB 2</li>
    <li class="tab_title " id="tab-3-title" data-tab-number="3"><span class="icon-plus-circled"></span>TAB 3</li>
    <li class="tab_title " id="tab-4-title" data-tab-number="4"><span class="icon-mail-1"></span>TAB 4</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child(4)`, in the case you want the **4th child** of anything:

```css
.rt_tabs li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #99c;
}
```

```html
<div class="rt_tabs clearfix  left tab-style-2" id="single-product-details" data-tab-style="tab-style-2">
  <ul class="tab_nav hidden-xs">
    <li class="tab_title  active" id="tab-1-title" data-tab-number="1"><span class="icon-lightbulb"></span>TAB 1</li>
    <li class="tab_title " id="tab-2-title" data-tab-number="2"><span class="icon-home"></span>TAB 2</li>
    <li class="tab_title " id="tab-3-title" data-tab-number="3"><span class="icon-plus-circled"></span>TAB 3</li>
    <li class="tab_title " id="tab-4-title" data-tab-number="4"><span class="icon-mail-1"></span>TAB 4</li>
  </ul>
```

Other ways to do (in this particular example):

1. Use the id: `#tab-4-title {}`.
2. Use the attribute selector: `[data-tab-number="4"] {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your element already has an id, so its easy

```css
#tab-4-title{
        /*Whatever change you want*/
    }
```

Comment: Code snippet must be used when you have something that has both HTML, CSS, or something that shows a working demo.

Comment: Didn't know. Edited it. Although now it looks like i've left comments all over. Is there a way to write code snippets for CSS but not working code?

Comment: Why did you remove the syntax highlighting. I just asked you to remove the code snippet alone.

Comment: Hey your code solved it for me! Thank you very much!

Comment: @ishaan I made it right for you and you again screwed up. LoL. `:)`

Comment: Ohh I do that quite often. :P

Comment: Nice! Keep it up then! LoL.

Answer (score 0):

`.tab_nav li:nth-child(4)` targets the 4th `li` child of `.tab_nav`. Or in this case `.tab_nav li:last-child` should also work.

More information on nth-child: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0):

Use the id:

```
#tab-4-title {...}
```

Use a attribute selector:

```
[data-tab-number="4"] {...}
```

Use a pseudo-selector:

```
li:nth-child(4) {...}
li:last-child {...}
li:nth-last-child(1) {...}
li:last-of-type {...}
```

There are several other possibilities.